# JavaScript - Why won't my function hold anything longer than a few characters?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    function hover(description) {
        console.log(description);
        document.getElementById('pricehover').innerHTML = description;
    }
</script>
```

I am using the above script to create a list that gives information on hover which appears to the right of the list. I use the following on list items within the HTML.

```
<li class="pricegrid" onmouseover="hover('<h1>100 Euros</h1> <br> <p>Pricing includes etc etc</p>')">Pedicure Behandling</li>
```

And the description is added to the following div

```
<div id="pricehover">Hover over the items to the left to see the price and description.
</div>
```

My problem is that my description cannot hold more than a few characters when I want to, if possible, completely style the div content with a whole pageworth of description including images. Can anyone explain why this isn't working or possible and perhaps give me a way to do what I want to do?

Thankyou.

EDIT: I made a pen here. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXwwag

Comment: Maybe unescaped html breaks the function call?

Comment: I don't know of any limit to the length of the html string you can assign to innerHTML.

Comment: Means?? Can you show your output ?

Comment: could you make a pen or tell what you are passing the function?

Comment: @Vandervals Look at his 2nd code block...

Comment: working fine in chrome https://jsfiddle.net/bdo6k0h0/

Comment: @Siguza he sais he is trying to include images and styles, not the code he shows here

Comment: @Vandervals No, he says he wants to be able to do that.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXwwag

Comment: @Siguza If I try to add normal div information and styling, it simply doesn't show anything!

Comment: @RickyPayne Could you add an example of the code styling that is not working for you? The examples on the pen are working fine. Something tells me it's probably an issue with the quotes not being escaped correctly, but without the actual code that fails it's almost impossible to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the content (any HTML markup) you want to show inside the li element itself in a hidden div, and then swap it into the right side div when you hover.

Codepen forked from yours - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doGXeV

HTML (change li)

```
<li class="pricegrid" onmouseover="hover(this)">Pedicure Behandling<div><h1>100 Euros</h1> <br> <p>Pricing includes etc etc</p></div></li>
```

JavaScript (change hover)

```
function hover(t) {
    document.getElementById('pricehover').innerHTML = t.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
}
```

CSS (class for hiding) - you could also just add it to the inline styles of the li's inner div, but that would be messy.

```
.pricegrid > div
{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this pen, I created.
No javascript
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpVVmM

```
ul{
  width:200px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
.description{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:300px;

  transform:translate(200px,0);   
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  display:none;
}

li:hover > div.description{
  display:block;
}
   <ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum.<div class='description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div></li>
  <li>Maxime, cupiditate.<div class='description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div></li>
  <li>A, ratione.<div class='description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas.</div></li>
  <li>Asperiores, labore?<div class='description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div></li>
  <li>Fugit, amet.<div class='description'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, accusamus?</div></li>
</ul>
```

Maybe dl>dt+dd is a better semantic markup for you, btw.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp

Comment: But I want to have a single Div positioned by the right of my list which will change according to which list item one hovers on. The aim being for said Div to be quite big and full of information such as images etc.